# rsync only particular file types in subdirectories with a fixed maximum depth

Tags: rsync, filter

I want to sync all *.sh files in exactly one sub directory. I tried this cmd but all files in a directory are synced instead of only particular file types.

```
rsync -vr -n --include="*.sh" --exclude="*/*/" --prune-empty-dirs /source /target
```

I also tried adding a filter like

```
--filter="+ *.sh"
```

but this did not change the result.
Another filter

```
rsync -vr -n --include="*.sh" --filter="-! *.sh" --exclude="*/*/" --prune-empty-dirs
```

gives me an empty list. If I exclude "*" I also exclude "*.sh"...
What is wrong? Thanks!

The depth should be one - the name of the subdirectory is not known. For example,

```
home/subdirectory1/subsubdirectory/subsubsubdirectory/file.sh
home/subdirectory1/file1.sh
home/subdirectory2/file2.sh
home/subdirectory3/file
```

In the above example `rsync` should start in home, sync directory hierarchy and only the files `file1.sh` and `file2.sh`

Comment: What do you mean by "in exactly one sub directory"? Do you mean you know what subdirectory the files are in? If so, what's the name or path of that directory?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why did you use the `-r` option if you don't want to descend into all subdirectories (you said "in one subdirectory")? Would `rsync -v /source/*.sh /target` not do the trick?

Comment: You write, "_rsync only special file types_" and then you say you want to copy `*.sh` files. The word _special_ has a particular meaning (devices, pipes, etc.). On the other hand, `*.sh` files aren't special; they just have three characters on the end of the filename.

Comment: You're right! Sorry for making my first question not clear enough! Note to me: always add an example for clarification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples don't seem to match your description. I think what you are saying you want is this,

- match all the `*.sh` files in an unknown subdirectory immediately underneath your `/home`
- put the files in the unknown subdirectory on the target
- do not include `/home` in the destination path

Looking from `/home`, this command will match all files `*/*.sh` and copy them and their partial paths to the target. (Remove the `--dry-run` if you are happy with the intended result.)

```
rsync --dry-run -avR /home/./*/*.sh /target
```

For example, `/home/subdir/file.sh` will be copied to `/target/subdir/file.sh`

Comment: That's it! Can't believe that it's so easy and I got lost with unnecessary --include/--exclude! Thank you very much for pointing me back to the track!

Comment: @AlexanderFieroch pleased it works for you. The `--relative` (`-R`) flag can be really useful in these kind of situations, particularly with its `/./` place marker

Comment: Yes, I tried `-R` and `/./` with and without - great flags in this situation that simplify a lot. Thanks!